# Adding OkHttp custom interceptor to Feign client

Tags: java, rest, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm having problems to set up a global `OkHttp` interceptor for my `@FeignClient` beans. I'm not experiencing any error, but the interceptor is being ignored.

My understanding is that Spring Cloud's auto configuration should pick the `OkHttpClient.Builder` bean that I'm declaring and use it to create the underlying `OkHttpClient` instances, but I might be wrong about this.

Here are the relevant parts of my Spring app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients(defaultConfiguration = FeignConfig.class)    
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder(MyInterceptor interceptor) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyInterceptor implements okhttp3.Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request request = chain.request();

        System.out.println("Hey there, this is my request: " + request);

        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        System.out.println("Hey there, this is my response: " + response);

        return response;
    }

}
```

The `intercept` method above is never called. I need `MyInterceptor` to be a Spring bean, because I need to inject other dependencies to it.

---

```
@FeignClient(name = "myClient", fallback = MyClientFallback.class)
public interface MyClient {

    // method declarations
}
```

---

```
@Component
public class MyClientFallback implements MyClient {

    // method fallback implementations
}
```

---

Here's the relevant part of my `application.properties` file:

```
feign.hystrix.enabled = true
feign.okhttp.enabled = true

ribbon.eureka.enabled = false
ribbon.eager-load.enabled = true
ribbon.eager-load.clients = myClient

myClient.ribbon.listOfServers = <IP_LIST>
myClient.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval = 10000
```

---

As you see from the properties declared above, I'm not using Eureka and I'm using Ribbon to load balance my rest client. I'm also using Hystrix to enable fallback responses and I have set the `feign.okhttp.enabled` property to `true`.

---

Below is the info about dependecies config and versions...

Spring Boot version is `2.0.3.RELEASE` and Spring Cloud version is `Finchley.SR1`, while `OkHttp` version is `3.11.0`.

In my `pom.xml` file, I have this `spring-cloud-dependencies` config:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        ...

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have also included the following Spring Boot and Spring Cloud dependencies, along with the `OkHttp` dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    ...

</dependencies>
```

Comment: How do you create feign client with provided builder? I think your builder is not used.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I think that Spring autoconfiguration should pick the builder I have declared and use it to create the underlying `OkHttp` client.

Comment: How your Feign client is created?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I'm letting that part to Spring Cloud

Comment: is class   MyInterceptor  compiling. I see missing return

Comment: @NomanKhan This is a simplified example. Everything is compiling and working fine, except for the interceptor, which is never called. I will add a dummy return statement for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should provide an `OkHttpClient` bean as [stated in the doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults):

> The OkHttpClient and ApacheHttpClient feign clients can be used by setting feign.okhttp.enabled or feign.httpclient.enabled to true, respectively, and having them on the classpath. You can customize the HTTP client used by providing a bean of either ClosableHttpClient when using Apache or OkHttpClient whe using OK HTTP.

https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/feign/okhttp/OkHttpClient.java

Comment: Did you use `Feign OkHttpClient`? (not the normal OkHttpClient). Also, try to annotated your `OkHttpClient` with `@Primary`

Comment: Your solution is correct, I apologize for my previous comments. The wrapper class `feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient` was not in the classpath, so Spring auto configuration wasn't being triggered. Once I discovered which dependency I had to include, it´s enough to provide a bean of `okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder` class, as I was doing, and Spring will take care of everything. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to let Spring auto configuration do its job.

In order for that to happen, the following dependency must be removed from the `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following one must be manually included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Once this is done, everything works as expected with the provided configuration.

Comment: Hi Federico, I am facing the same issue. For me request and response to the external service is not printed by following the same code.

Comment: @TheNightsWatch Hi! I just included that missing dependency and everything worked fine.

Comment: Ok. instead of  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency> we need to add that dependency? or we need both Okhttp depedencies?

Comment: @TheNightsWatch I've double checked my app. You only need the `<groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId> <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>` dependency, the `<groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId> <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>` one isn't necessary. Thanks for asking about this, I will edit my answer above.

Comment: Any ways to check if we success "enable" okhttp? it doesn't show `okhttp mode on` or any obvious info in log

Comment: @user1686407 Sorry, I don't know if there's some logging message that notifies about enabling okhttp. You can always try to change the log level to TRACE or DEBUG and see what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** is to use OkHttpClient. Add pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and configure a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class FeignConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public OkHttpClient client() {
    return new OkHttpClient();
  }
}
```

**Explanation**: For 401, 407 and some other HTTP-status responses, bodies are replaced with `null` by HTTP clients used in Open Feign by default.

[From OpenFeign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/260#issuecomment-219662075): Currently in the feign.Default client there is a streaming mode enabled. You can see in the `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` following lines of code :

```
if (respCode == HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) { 
  if (streaming()) { 
    disconnectInternal(); 
    throw new HttpRetryException (RETRY_MSG2, HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED); 
  }
}
```

So if the streaming is enabled and you have **401 HTTP response** code you will get empty errorStream, because there is no initialization. The feign client will try to get the errorStream as a body because there is a check

```
if (status >= 400) { 
  stream = connection.getErrorStream(); 
} else { stream = connection.getInputStream(); }
```